# Проблема c версиями Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play

Всем привет. Очень и очень нужна ваша помощь.

Давно задавал такой вопрос на *stackoverflow*, но в силу занятости забил на проблему, а предлогаемые решения там не работают, да и народ не понял мой ломанный английский.

Суть проблемы в том, что на клиентских устройствах, а это планшеты с Андройдом 4.2.2, версия *Google Play Service 2.0.12*.

Мое приложение использует карты. На устройствах клиентов не работает, пока не обновить Сервис.

Клиенты используют девайс в рабочих условиях и в данном контексте они не будут логиниться под Гугл акканутом и что-то там обновлять.

Но, к прмеру в этом же Андройде уже есть гугл карта, и помоему это свежей версии, как у них работает, а у меня нет?

В *AndroidManifest.xml* у меня все как надо - ключ, поддержка *OpenGl 2.0*. 
Вот это то же есть

```
<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Но на клиентских устройствах не работает, на моём тестовом работает.
Работаю в *Idea*, проект *Google Play Service* само собой добавлен и выставлен module dependancy из моего приложения  на *Google Play Service*.

Я уже не знаю что делать.

Comment: Вчера боролся с подключение гуглосервисов к проекту, но строка 

    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
    

 так и не заработала, пришлось вставить просто число, и вечно сыпится ошибка 

     E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

Как вы подключили её?

Comment: @ua6xh `<integer name="google_play_services_version">4030500</integer>` 
брал отсюда ...\android_sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\version.xml

Answer (score 1):

Схожую проблему (но только связанную с наличием/отсутствием in-app billing) я решал проверкой при запуске приложения наличия соответствующего интента:

```
public boolean isIabServiceAvailable(Context context) {
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentServices(intent, 0);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }
```

Очевидно, что в данном случае можно применить похожую идею. Надо озаботиться позиционированием интента, который используется (то ли карты то ли openGL осталось непонятным).

Если интент не биндится, то можно или вывести на экран интеллигентное сообщение с просьбой обновить Play Services или направить на его обновление.

Как то так.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в том, что вы используете версию Play Services для мин ОС 2.3, а в манифесте прописали мин версию SDK 2.2. Соответственно, люди качают ваше приложение на 2.2 и у них ничего не работает. Либо юзайте более раннюю версию Play Services либо увеличьте мин версию ОС в манифесте(minSDK). Последний вариант самый плохой.

Comment: мне кажется вы не внимательно прочитали вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Это конечно не совсем ответ на вопрос. Но я вам предлагаю раз клиенты не хотят логиниться в google play, просто вместе с apk Вашего проекта, отправлять им apk требуемой версии google play service. Если я не путаю обновить их можно и не подключаясь к google play.

Большой сложности установить вручную 2 apk или 1 я не вижу, думаю и  ваши клиенты сильно возмущаться не будет.